# What is the asymptotic relation between functions

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I want to know the reason of following given relations:

1. `n < (log n)^log n`
2. `log log n = O(root(log n))`
3. `(log n) != omega(log(n!))`
4. `log(log*n) < log*(log n)`

base of all log is 2. Obviously I know the answers but I do not know how to find them.I could also see one can not find these just by putting values of `n` all the time. As for 1st relation it does not hold for `n=2`. What is the effect of applying above function to large value of `n`? Can anyone come with universal solution (or guide me a way) so that I can find relation on applying different combination of above (or extra function not given) functions on `n`. For example, `log*log(root(log(n!)))` with `loglog*(log(root(n!)))`

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, asymptotic means as approaches infinity (as the function approachs its *asymptote*).

So for a rough estimate, use really large n.

For a more precise definition and discussion see [Asymptotic Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis), or any intro to computer science text.